# Testflight Profile Installation Failed, the SCEP server return an invalid response

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

One of my user is having trouble installing the **TestFlight App** (not Apple's TestFlight).

He encountered the error: "Profile Installation Failed, the SCEP server return an invalid response."

[image: Error]

I advise him to follow the steps listed here:
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402816-registration-issues

He told me that he has no profile installed in his profiles and after following the steps, he still encounter the same error.

I at a lost as to what to do now and any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: Want to add that the user was able to install the app successfully without me doing anything, might be a problem with testflight's backend.

Comment: This is the reply from testflight support in case anyone else find it helpful "This problem usually occurs when the device is experiencing network connection issues. Strong firewalls or proxies can also cause this error. Can you try connecting to another Wifi connection, maybe at another location or at a cafe? If the device has an internet service plan, disable the Wifi and try using the internet service instead. "

Comment: Restart device (hard reset) and it seemed to work?

Comment: i am having the same issue on iPhone 5s and iOS 8.1.1 and my network is fine...no firewalls...answer from TestFlight is bogus! I rebooted the device and issue still there.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Safari or network. I cleared the cookie and ensured private browsing is disabled - no issue. The cert installation happens outside of Safari and it always fails with the same error.

Comment: are they using the old TestFlight provided app, or the new Apple provided app ???

Comment: Problem persists with iOS 8.1.2. Notably Tesflight reports my device's OS as "iOS 12b435" when I had iOS 8.1.1 installed, and "iOS 12b440" with 8.1.2

Comment: Can someone confirm that it is a new problem with test flight appears on iOS 8?

Comment: @user1888440 The user was able to install the app later in the day. I have no idea why the problem was resolved, perhaps it was as the testflight support state, the user was experiencing network issue.

Comment: @hasan83 this is not related to test flight beta from apple, this is with http://testflightapp.com

Comment: @thndrkiss Thank for response. but, I know that. I thought maybe its a test flight app bug with this specific iOS version.

Answer (score 29):

I finally got my testers to get past this SCEP error. Hopefully this works for you too.

**Workaround:**

1. Open the iOS Settings app, select Safari then tap on "Clear History and Website Data"
2. Open the Safari app and go to testflightapp.com
3. Log into your TestFlight account
4. On the "Connect this device by installing profile" screen, tap the green button "Connect Device"
5. Tap "Install" on the "Install Profile" screen
6. If you have an unlock passcode on your device, you may be will be prompted to enter it
7. When the SCEP error comes up, tap "OK"
8. Tap "Cancel" on the "Install Profile" screen
9. You should then be redirected to TestFlight in Safari with the "Device successfully connected!" message

Comment: Yeah this is the work around i am managing with but the problem is i want to completely avoid this as it is bad user experience :(.

Comment: How is this a workaround? You still need to have the profile installed on your device to be able to run/install the app. The only thing you accomplish here is being able to see the apps you have access to, which is nice i guess but still unusable.

Comment: This worked for us - even though we had the error it did install the profile successfully.  We didn't need to clear the Safari history.  One possibility is that we'd previously used TestFlight a long time ago, there may have been a profile from the prior installation present.

Comment: The need for that certificate to get installed is for two purposes. 1 for acquiring the UDID and other is to put up a short cut on home screen, i guess this has nothing to do with the app installation, if it is enterprise adhoc then there is no need to know the UDID if it is adhoc on a personal program then we need udid, i guess that is also getting fulfilled by hitting candle as @stcharchar mentioned in the answer

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Tapping cancel results in the profile not being installed, which prevents installations.

Answer (score 4):

Ok follow these steps,

1 - Delete TestFlight Web Clip or icon from home screen.

2 - Delete TestFlight Profile

3 - Important (Go to Safari in settings and Clear History and Website Data)

4. Restart your device.
5. Login to https://testflightapp.com/m/login on Mobile Safari.
6. Tap Connect Device.

Hope this worked for you :D

Bye!

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue. The Testflight-App from the AppStore won't install, saying iOS 8 is required (although we have other iPads with iOS 7.x running the app). The "invalid response"-error occured when logging into [testflightapp.com](http://www.testflightapp.com) on the device and trying to register it as proposed [in testflightapp.com's Help section](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1306270-%22this-build-requires-ios-7-0%22-what-do-i-do-).

I solved this issue by clearing Safari's cookies and data (Settings -> Safari -> Clear Cache) and then restarting the device.

After going to testflightapp.com again, the device was already connected an everything worked. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

We just saw this yesterday. The issue was the firewall at work! I had the user turn off Wifi and just connect on the cellular network. It worked fine for her then. If the device is an iPod, just wait until you get home, hopefully your home wifi is different from your work wifi.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's often caused by firewall rules.
Try using another wifi/cellular network.

https://twitter.com/testflightapp/status/389838663494156290

Comment: A link like this is not generally good practice.  Even though it might answer the question, adding the relevant content here allows for a quicker overview of the answer and also, handles the event that the link disappears.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Fixed it.

Comment: we tried it on a normal home as well as corporate wi-fi,cellular only but still did not work

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have selected to build the program under "iOS Device" instead of my actual "iPhone" device. When this has happened none of my users were able to download and this error shows up.

This is also a common issue when you didn't register his UDID correct on the provisioning profile on developer.apple.com. Double check your provisioning profile entry of his UDID and if it is incorrect change it to the correct one. Build, export and upload your app again and it should be fine.

This has happened to me twice. Good luck!

Comment: i verified it, it is registered, All the users are getting this issue. may be server side stuff :(