# Can't install TestFlight web clip profile

Tags: ios, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

I recently had my device replaced at the apple store. Installing builds from TestFlight failed, so I logged in to http://testflightapp.com in Mobile Safari, went to https:/www.testflightapp.com/m/connectdevice, and tapped "Reconnect Device". The profile downloads and attempts to install, but consistently fails with the error "The SCEP server configuration is not supported."

[This SO discussion of a similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696155/testflight-profile-installation-failed-the-scep-server-return-an-invalid-respon) suggests it's a firewall issue, but I've tried it on my home wifi, on 3G, and LTE, always with the same results.

I've also tried rebooting my device a couple of times, to no avail.

[image]

Comment: I've got the same issue :/

Comment: Same for me on multiple devices. Are you all on iOS 8.1.2?

Comment: I've only tried on one device, which is running 8.1.2. I'll try on a different device tomorrow when I'm in the office.

Comment: Tried again yesterday on another network and it worked. Not sure if it was the network or Apple fixed something.