# "The SCEP server configuration is not supported" when trying to use TestFlight

Tags: ipad, testflight

I'm new to all this TestFlight scene, all I know is that when I try to install an app through TF in my iPad, I get that error when the profile tries to install.

I've googled a bit, but most answers are not related to TF, but to other platforms.

Any ideas?.

Comment: Same problem, no jailbreak. Guess it's a bug on TF's side?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. I think TF is having some issues with their server. TF will still work if you have any device that had TF profile installed previously

Comment: Could this be related to Jailbreaking? I keep one device jailbroken to test protection against IAP hacks and that's the same device that i can't add today.

Comment: My iPad is not jailbroken, so at least in my case it's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ignore it. Just tap "Ok", "Cancel", "Cancel" and voila your device is connected.

Some other tips could be found here:

[Testflight Profile Installation Failed, the SCEP server return an invalid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696155/testflight-profile-installation-failed-the-scep-server-return-an-invalid-respon)